# Azure Service Fabric - HTTP 504 for apps hosted on Windows Containers

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful, windows-container, service-fabric-actor

I have created an Azure Service Fabric Cluster using "Windows 2016 DataCenter with Containers" OS and enabled Reverse Proxy listening on Port 80 on the cluster. I have deployed a sample container application on this cluster.

I am able to access it via public load balancer but when I try to access it via Reverse Proxy then I am getting random HTTP 504 (Gateway timeout) errors.

Has anyone experienced 504 timeout errors while accessing container hosted apps via Reverse Proxy? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Gaurav

Comment: I've seen this on Windows 10 using Docker for Windows, trying to get web resources from within a container. Let me circle this with Windows people here at MS and see what I can dig up.

Comment: I raised a github issue https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/227  ...Looks like this is a WinNAT limitation